# Portfolio release for photographing children under 18?

Tags: legal

I will  be photographing a school's events and it's students for a week. However, I am not sure if the standard portfolio release will suffice given the age of the subjects.

Important background:

- I am primarily there as a teacher, but took the opportunity to build my portfolio as this is a new genre for me.
- I have the *verbal* go-ahead from the event organiser of course, but at the same time,  given that the children will be between 13-14, I wonder what I should do.
- My intents for use are only to advertise my services, non-commercial, no libel. However they would not always be background members, some pictures would be group shots, candid moments etc.

My best guess is that having the event organizer sign the release should be easier than 60 + children without a guardian, also because they are travelling from another continent to the EU. I imagine the event organiser is responsible for them during their visit.

Comment: Which country are you doing this in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a story as related to me by a friend.

> "As an employee of a school i once photographed a school play
>   performed for  the public in the evening. The principle of the school
>   went to the district, i was called in and essentially treated as if i
>   was child predator meaning to do harm to children. If not for my union
>   representation i would have been fired or worse, charged with intent
>   to ?. The  photos were not published nor shared publicly other then a
>   few prints i made and gave to the person in the photo

.

**Do not photograph any child without the parent or the guardians permission before hand**.

In many school districts You can not photograph a school building without permission from the district and there may even be laws forbidding it.

***You need to speak with the school district before any of this is to take place and find out what is allowed AND what is required for you do be taking photos at a school**.

Verbal go ahead means nothing, even from the district. 
get it writing and have a model release by the parent of every child you will be photographing before any photos are taken.*

My Friend added the following to there story for your benefit.

> **"I AM NOT A LAWYER**,  I am also not a pedophile but i was treated like that was my intention simply because i photographed a school
>   play. Accusations regardless of what the reality is are personally
>   hurtful, socially and professionally damaging and possibly a threat to
>   your personal safety".

Comment: This. There's an expectation, at least in my schools (USA), that you'd be photographed at school activities by teachers or students for use in school newspapers or the yearbook. If you are attempting to use these photos outside of a school endeavor, then you should seek a parent to sign a release for every.single.child who is in a photo you wish to use.

Comment: Expectations mean nothing. It just takes one  accusation ( false or otherwise )  to change your life.